# CSS: is there a hierarchy with height values?

Tags: html, css

I want to use the calc function for my height value, but some older browsers don't support it and it makes the site look awful.

```
 .container2 {
        height: calc(100% - 87px);
        height: -webkit-calc(100% - 87px);
        height: -moz-calc(100% - 87px);
        height: 500px;
    }
```

I thought if I layed it out like this that browsers that support the calc function would use those first but if it doesn't then it would use the basic value `500px` in this case.

Is there a way to use calc height first, then plain `500px` height if the browser doesn't support it?

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it backwards: browsers will process all declarations in the same rule and use the last one that is applicable.

So, two things: your fallback `500px` value needs to go on the top, and you need to have the unprefixed `calc()` value at the bottom to ensure that browsers use the standardized implementation over their vendor-specific ones when applicable:

```
.container2 {
    height: 500px;
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 87px);
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 87px);
    height: calc(100% - 87px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As i know, you have to put the fallback on the very first:

```
.container2 {
    height: 500px;
    height: calc(100% - 87px);
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 87px);
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 87px);
}
```